# InvalidCiphertext exception when decrypting ciphertext

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm working in a new protocol for secure communication and I'm having problems to decrypt the ciphertext.

The data packet is saved in a uint8_t* variable and encrypted. Until this part is all going well. But when I try to decrypt I got the followings problems:

1) If I send the vector and the size (it's really 20 but I just want to decrypt the last 16 bytes):

```
CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption decryptor;
decryptor.SetKeyWithIV( key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv );

CryptoPP::StringSource ss( vector+4, 16 , true,
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( decryptor,
             new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) ) );
```

I get this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext'
  what():  StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

2) If I just send the vector without size:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss( vector+4, true,
       new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( decryptor,
              new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) ) );
```

The programs runs but I just get all 00:

```
Text Encrypted (20 bytes)
8c 97 b7 d8 74 80 3d 9f 9f 62 2e 93 38 c7 d1 b de a4 21 80 

Text Decrypted (16 bytes)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 68 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I read that it could be that the key is not generated correctly, but I'm working with a size of 16 and here is how I do it:

```
 byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[      CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
 memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
 memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );
```

3) I also tried to cast the vector to char and send it like an string:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( (vector + 4) ), 16, true,
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( decryptor,
            new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) ) );
```

But again I get the same thing:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext'
  what():  StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

Please help, I have tried for days to figure out what's wrong. This is taking me too long and I can't find the solutions.

Does anyone have any idea on what might be happening?

Let me know if you need further details, code or anything.

Edit:

4) One more thing that I tried was (another way to construct the decrypter):

```
CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );


CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( (vector + 4) ), 16 );
stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
```

But I get the same:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext'
  what():  StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

Edit2:

The vector is created with this line (the way the vector is fulled is a quite complicated to put it here because I am using a platform for network encoding) :

```
uint8_t* vector;
```

Edit3:

This is how I encrypt the vector.

```
CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
        stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( (vector + 4) ), 16 );
        stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
```

And after that I put the ciphertext again in the vector:

```
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
for(int i=0;i < 16; i++){
    *(vector+ i + 4) = (ciphertext[i]) ; 
}
```

Comment: Post exactly what `vector` is.  It cannot be determined by the code you posted.  If it's not `std::vector`, it's not a good idea to name your variables the same as a standard C++ class.

Comment: @Niemand - The information provided in your third and fourth edits conflict. The third edit uses `StreamTransformationFilter::DEFAULT_PADDING`, which is `StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING`. The fourth edit uses `StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING`. You really should reduce this to a minimal working example of actual code you are using.

Comment: @Niemand - Please remove the 4th edit from the question, and add it as an answer. Then, accept your own answer. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was encoding with padding and trying to decrypt it without. So I add not only in the encryption but in the descryption that it should work without padding.

Creation of the Key and IV:

```
CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV( key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv );
```

Encryption:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss( vector + 4 , 16, true, 
     new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( encryptor,
          new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ),
              CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING
     ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
); // StringSource
```

Decryption:

```
CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption decryptor;
    decryptor.SetKeyWithIV( key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv );

        CryptoPP::StringSource ss( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( (vector + 4) ), 16, true,
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( decryptor,
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING) );
```

I did this because I don't want to work with padding anymore.

Comment: *"I did this because I don't want to work with padding anymore"* - be careful with this. That means you will always have to work data in block-size (16-byte) chunks. You can't make AES work on less that that size.

Comment: Also, I don't know what's at `vector[0 - 3]`. Even though its not encrypted, it should probably be MAC'd as AAD. Again, see [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: At `vector[0-3]` there is an encoding vector, I also work with some variation of [Network Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_network_coding).

Comment: I wouldn't call this an answer, it doesn't solve the problem of why the exception is thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext'
    what():  StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

This is easy enough to fix. Catch a Crypto++ `InvalidCiphertext` exception. See the [InvalidCiphertext Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_invalid_ciphertext.html).

### -----

```
If I just send the vector without size:

CryptoPP::StringSource ss( vector+4, true, ...
```

I think this might be matching the following `StringSource` constructor, which means the length is `true`, which probable means 1. To add insult to injury the attached `StreamTransformationFilter` is being coerced into the `bool pumpAll`:

```
StringSource (const byte *string, size_t length, bool pumpAll, BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL)
```

You should probably enable warnings to catch these sorts of things. `-Wall -Wextra` are good choices. (Nothing will help the coercion of the pointer to the `bool`, though. See, for example, [No pointer conversion warning for "bool" in C/C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-09/msg00293.html) on the GCC mailing list).

### -----

```
If I send the vector and the size (it's really 20 but I
just want to decrypt the last 16 bytes):

...
CryptoPP::StringSource ss( vector+4, 16 , true, ...
```

I don't think this is going to work as expected. CBC mode is not a random access mode (but I may not be parsing things correctly):

```
CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
cout << "Random access: " << enc.IsRandomAccess() << endl;
```

Results in:

```
Random access: 0
```

I'm fairly certain its not going to work at byte sizes. You might be able to do it by adding a layer above the decryptor, but you will have to manage the initialization vector, then decrypt a block, and finally return the offest into the block.

### -----

You should probably do something like the following. Its not efficient because it copes a `string` to a `vector`, but I wanted to try an use vectors since you seem to be using them.

`encrypted.CopyTo(f2)` is where you put your socket code. Your code will not need `encrypted.CopyTo(f2)`.

```
// Creates the memory block and zero's it.
SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH), iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

string m1;
vector<char> v1;

m1 = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country";
copy(m1.begin(), m1.end(), back_inserter(v1));

CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

ByteQueue encrypted;
StreamTransformationFilter f1(enc, new Redirector(encrypted));

f1.PutWord32((uint32_t)v1.size(), BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
f1.Put((const unsigned char *) &v1[0], v1.size());
f1.MessageEnd();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

string m2;
vector<char> v2;

CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption dec;
dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

ByteQueue decrypted;
StreamTransformationFilter f2(dec, new Redirector(decrypted));

encrypted.CopyTo(f2);
f2.MessageEnd();

uint32_t len;
decrypted.GetWord32(len, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);

v2.resize(len);
decrypted.Get((unsigned char *) &v2[0], v2.size());

copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(m2));

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cout << "Message: " << m1 << endl;
cout << "Decrypted: " << m2 << endl;
```

It produces the expected results:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Message: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
Decrypted: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country
```

### -----

Regarding your use of `vector + 4`: once the cipher text is decrypted, you can seek in it, and do things like read a length from it. That's what this does:

```
// Ciphertext is already decrypted
uint32_t len;
decrypted.GetWord32(len, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
```

If you just want to discard the value, then try:

```
decrypted.Skip(4);
```

But then you'll have to figure out how to size your `vector`.

### -----

> I'm working in a new protocol for secure communication

Secure communications usually provides both confidentiality and authenticity assurances. You seem to be missing the latter since CBC mode only provides confidentiality.

It might be a good idea to use something that already exists, like IPSec (preferred) or TLS (will do in a pinch). Also, key agreement is going to be a pain point. Its another reason to consider using something like IPSec or TLS.

If you can't use something already available, then you should use an [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode so you get confidentiality and authenticity combined into a single mode. Try [EAX](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Eax_mode), [GCM](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gcm_mode) or [CCM](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ccm_mode) mode.

If you do, then then change is fairly trivial:

```
    EAX< AES >::Encryption enc;
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

    ByteQueue encrypted;
    AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter f1(enc, new Redirector(encrypted));
```

And:

```
    EAX< AES >::Decryption dec;
    dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

    ByteQueue decrypted;
    AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter f2(dec, new Redirector(decrypted));
```

### -----

You can print the cipher text by copying it to an encoder. Copying is non-destructive (unlike moving it with `TransferTo`):

```
string encoded;
HexEncoder encoder(new StringSink(encoded));
encrypted.CopyTo(encoder);
encoder.MessageEnd();
```

Fox CBC mode (less secure):

```
Encrypted: 7F9FFCAB00704EC79BB5F19C48FE7C668033B16F52E7E00671A38A06F4A7426E7FE31
95CA6A83C7414A76C250B42E63143C93E7A6B97B6304C5782DE3E62BD545706A9F62CD7AD57BC374
19B7510EBED
```

For EAX mode (more secure):

```
Encrypted: B75347EB75DF8E1F0424979E91CEECD455F5727B506A8AA932AF07E1DF6A7B037A245
FEC7A2270BFAB8110226769E1C0A12E95C455E9C714AF28DA330A2B01B3F2D541D4E68276193C018
7BA0246166AD26624E848EC8330D3
```

The extra bytes in EAX mode are the authentication tag. Its used to detect accidental and malicious tampering.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, but I still a little bit lost here. "vector"  is a big space of memory where I have all my encoded packets. So I decrypt the last 16 bytes and switch to the next packet, and so on. - This decryption is just an small part of the protocol and all the rest is working with uint8_t, that's why I can't change it. I'm getting confuse because I just want to take 16 bytes, then decrypt them and put them again in the vector. And it's getting more and more complicated. I added how I encrypt and you can see the `vector + 4` working, maybe I could do something similar?

Comment: *" "vector" is a big space of memory where I have all my encoded packets"* - in C++, `vector` is a data structure. See [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).