# BouncyCastle gets error 'public key presented not for certificate signature' for retrieved ECPublicKey

Tags: x509certificate, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, pkcs11interop

I am trying to use `BouncyCastle` library for generating `X509Certificate` in a `.Net` application, meanwhile i want to use keys stored in `HSM`.
My solution is generating `EC` key-pair in `HSM`, returning `ECPoint` and key lable to `.Net` application, and regenerate an elliptic key for signature generation.

After generating elliptic key, While checking its validity i got this error: `UnManagedException: Public key presented not for certificate signature`. This is the part of code from which Error raises:

```
X509Certificate rootCertificate = new X509Certificate (
            new X509CertificateStructure (
                 TBS_Structure, 
                 AlgorithmID, 
                 new BitDERString(signature));
rootCertificate.Verify(PublicKeyParam);
```

`PublicKeyParam` is `RSAKeyParameter` and rebuilt based on Exponent and Modolus extracted from the library which made key on HSM (and returned key parameters). `rootCertificate`'s algorithm is `SHA256WithRSAandMGF1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for X509 certificates, elliptic key-point with separated `r` and `s` parts are required. The key-point which `PKCS11Interop` returns from HSM is a concatenated `byte[]` of `r` and `s`. So you should break it into two `byte[]` and use following code instead of `signature` in `new BitDERString(signature)`:

```
new DerSequence(
    new DerInteger(new BigInteger(1, signature.Take(len/2).ToArray())),
    new DerInteger(new BigInteger(1, signature.Skip(len/2).ToArray()))
         ).GetDerEncodded()
```

This issue was explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868936/retrieve-ecc-public-key-from-base64-encoded-string) unintentionally but i couldn't get the point.